# Difference between sql * plus and sql loader

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, sql-loader

I am Oracle Data base Bigginner. I am Confusing with this two words sql * plus and sql loader,Any one Tell me the difference between SQL loader and SQL * PLUS?

Comment: Google is your friend

Answer (score 3):

[From](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b12170/qstart.htm) the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/ldr_concepts.htm):

SQL*Plus is an interactive and batch query tool that is installed with every Oracle Database Server or Client installation. It has a command-line user interface, a Windows Graphical User Interface (GUI) and the iSQL*Plus web-based user interface.

SQL*Plus has its own commands and environment, and it provides access to the Oracle Database. It enables you to enter and execute SQL, PL/SQL, SQL*Plus and operating system commands to perform the following:

Format, perform calculations on, store, and print from query results

Examine table and object definitions

Develop and run batch scripts

Perform database administration

You can use SQL*Plus to generate reports interactively, to generate reports as batch processes, and to output the results to text file, to screen, or to HTML file for browsing on the Internet. You can generate reports dynamically using the HTML output facility of SQL*Plus, or using the dynamic reporting capability of iSQL*Plus to run a script from a web page.





SQL*Loader loads data from external files into tables of an Oracle database. It has a powerful data parsing engine that puts little limitation on the format of the data in the datafile. You can use SQL*Loader to do the following:

Load data across a network if your data files are on a different system than the database.

Load data from multiple datafiles during the same load session.

Load data into multiple tables during the same load session.

Specify the character set of the data.

Selectively load data (you can load records based on the records' values).

Manipulate the data before loading it, using SQL functions.

Generate unique sequential key values in specified columns.

Use the operating system's file system to access the datafiles.

Load data from disk, tape, or named pipe.

Generate sophisticated error reports, which greatly aid troubleshooting.

Load arbitrarily complex object-relational data.

Use secondary datafiles for loading LOBs and collections.

Use either conventional or direct path loading. While conventional path loading is very flexible, direct path loading provides superior loading performance.

Answer (score 1):

**SQL* Plus** is installed with every Oracle Database Server or Client installation. It has a command-line user interface, a Windows Graphical User Interface (GUI) and the iSQL*Plus web-based user interface.
**SQL*** Loader loads data from external files into tables of an Oracle database.It can also be Load data across a network.

Answer (score 0):

SQL*plus is something that provides an access to the Oracle Database.
SQL Loader is you are loading the external data or files from your disk to Oracle database.